# Reason for sudden long GC pause

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am running my application for one day using the test batch in loop. 
One test batch runs for 4 hours and I run the same test batch for 30 loops and end up running smoothly for one day and suddenly there is a spike the end of the day for 20 seconds.

I already tuned the GC and see the attached pic,

[image: Sudden spike in the GC pause]

Suddenly by the end of the day I could see a spike in GC pause,

1) Why there is a sudden spike in the GC? NOTE : I am running the same test in loop and each test runs for 4 hours and suddenly there is a spike in 10th loop?
2) What could be the possibilities of it and How to track it?

Relevant part of the GC log:

```
{Heap before GC invocations=5451 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 8388608K, used 4872081K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005c0404000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 4096K, 614 young (2514944K), 19 survivors (77824K)
 Metaspace       used 38562K, capacity 39526K, committed 39888K, reserved 1085440K
  class space    used 4096K, capacity 4277K, committed 4352K, reserved 1048576K
2018-05-22T16:36:06.323+0000: 85842.817: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 161480704 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    4507344 bytes,    4507344 total
- age   2:   16799960 bytes,   21307304 total
- age   3:   15901408 bytes,   37208712 total
- age   4:   16061376 bytes,   53270088 total
, 20.3599018 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 16841.9 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 85846284.8, Avg: 85846414.4, Max: 85846458.0, Diff: 173.2]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 787.2, Avg: 1628.6, Max: 2662.7, Diff: 1875.5, Sum: 13029.0]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 13521.3, Avg: 14190.0, Max: 14460.0, Diff: 938.7, Sum: 113520.2]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 11, Avg: 27.8, Max: 50, Diff: 39, Sum: 222]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 165.8, Avg: 291.7, Max: 401.5, Diff: 235.7, Sum: 2333.4]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 0.7]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 78.1, Avg: 279.5, Max: 1353.4, Diff: 1275.3, Sum: 2235.6]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 3.8, Max: 5.0, Diff: 5.0, Sum: 30.6]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 5.1, Max: 15, Diff: 14, Sum: 41]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 317.6, Max: 1258.0, Diff: 1258.0, Sum: 2541.0]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 16667.6, Avg: 16711.3, Max: 16841.3, Diff: 173.7, Sum: 133690.5]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 85863125.6, Avg: 85863125.8, Max: 85863126.2, Diff: 0.6]
   [Code Root Fixup: 1.2 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [String Dedup Fixup: 5.9 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [Queue Fixup (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Table Fixup (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 1.6, Max: 5.9, Diff: 5.9, Sum: 12.6]
   [Clear CT: 1.1 ms]
   [Other: 3509.7 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 30.7 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 2.4 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 4.0 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 2339.6 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 3.5 ms]
   [Eden: 2380.0M(2380.0M)->0.0B(720.0M) Survivors: 76.0M->96.0M Heap: 4757.9M(8192.0M)->2395.9M(8192.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=5452 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 8388608K, used 2453393K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005c0404000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 4096K, 24 young (98304K), 24 survivors (98304K)
 Metaspace       used 38562K, capacity 39526K, committed 39888K, reserved 1085440K
  class space    used 4096K, capacity 4277K, committed 4352K, reserved 1048576K
}
 [Times: user=33.60 sys=5.40, real=20.36 secs] 
2018-05-22T16:36:26.684+0000: 85863.177: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 23.3452204 seconds, Stopping threads took: 1.5114697 seconds
2018-05-22T16:36:26.685+0000: 85863.179: [GC concurrent-string-deduplication, 6912.0B->64.0B(6848.0B), avg 88.1%, 0.0000411 secs]
```

Full GC logs [here](https://files.fm/u/2kmx484a)

**GC Configuration :**

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=10
-XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=30
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=400
```

**Java version - 8**

Comment: You should log the GC details to see what it's doing during the peaks.

Comment: @Kayaman added the gc logs

Comment: You're supposed to (at least) extract the relevant parts of the log and include them in the question, not dump the logs and expect free debugging.

Comment: @Kayaman sorry I thought u are expecting the complete logs, Could you let me know why there is a sudden spike If only the common test is running in a loop ?

Comment: Which version of Java are you running on and which GC settings are you using when you experience that?

Comment: The "Old Gen" graph on site you used shows heap usage for Old Gen is not falling after GC. That simple means there is memory leak, and GC pauses are longer, since GC can't find any memory to be freed. If you can't take heap dump (and use Eclipse MAT) when the problem occuress maybe just log result  `jmap -histo:live` every 5 minutes. It could point  why the leak occurs.

Comment: @Kayaman added the Java version and GC configuration

Comment: Those numbers look fishy, especially for a young collection, it spends more time in kernel space than it should and it doesn't spend 8x the CPU cycles compared to wall time, i.e. it's not fully using those 8 threads. You should check OS-level stats. Is it swapping? Do you actually have 8 CPU threads? Is the CPU oversubscribed? Did THP compaction run?

Comment: @the8472 we dont have swap memory configured, its a 8 core machine, How to perform THP compaction?

Comment: Read up on transparent huge pages (kernel feature). The defragmentation running is suspect #1. If that's not it then the `Humongous Register` would point at a second suspect, humongous allocations.

Comment: Am not a Linux guy, could you tell me how to collect all these please @the8472

Comment: Also if you look at the graph, for one day it was normal and suddenly it spiked, this is what confusing me

Answer (score 1):

I have a little question, how many cores or virtual CPUs do you have on that machine?

Sorry, I did not realize you have 8 cores something I'm missing is the value of Xms and Xmx, but I suppose you are using the same value to avoid resizing.

Based on my experience, I would prefer using parallel garbage collector if I were you. Do you have any special reason to use GC1?

I mean, I would use GC1 if I had a machine with more capabilities than yours I am talking about the number of cores and the heap that you are supposed to allocate. According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html):

> The Garbage-First (G1) garbage collector is a server-style garbage collector, targeted for multiprocessor machines with large memories.

What is more, I cannot see the configuration for the number of concurrent threads used by concurrent phases so I can imagine for those phases you are using 2 thread according to this information for [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector.htm#JSGCT-GUID-D74F3CC7-CC9F-45B5-B03D-510AEEAC2DAC). Unfortunately, I could not find the default value for Java 8.

> The maximum number of threads used for concurrent work. By default,
>   this value is -XX:ParallelGCThreads divided by 4

Thus, I think that with just 2 threads for the concurrent phase, there is more floating garbage, which should be processed during the update of remembered sets (Update RS) and perhaps that explains why this phase takes a lot of time.

With the number of cores that machine has and the memory your JVM is using, I would recommend you trying the parallel collector with these flags to see whether you can avoid this long pause

```
-XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms8192M -Xmx8192M -Xmn3072M -XX:SurvivorRatio=3 -Xss1024K -XX:MetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/some/path/ -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/some/path/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M
```

Last but not least, remember that with G1GC you should avoid Full GCs as much as possible because they are executed using just one thread as you can see [here](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/collecting-and-reading-g1-garbage-collector-logs-part-2)

> The third type of collection you may encounter, and the one we’re
>   working to avoid, is the Full GC. In G1, a Full GC is a single
>   threaded Stop The World (STW) pause which will evacuate and compact
>   all regions. There are three important pieces of information you can
>   get from the Full GC logs

I think this is going to be improved in [Java 10](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/307)

Best regards,

RCC

Comment: Total CPU core in this machine : 8 cores. Also its an SSD

Comment: Just for curiosity, how is your system doing?